# Value too long for type character varying(x) though my string is within range

Tags: django, postgresql

I am using phonenumber_field to store phone numbers.

```py
phone_number = PhoneNumberField(blank=False, max_length=12)
```

I also just switched from sqlite db to postgres and also ran makemigrations and migrate. The sqlite db works but I keep getting this error "Value too long for type character varying(x)" for postgresql even though I am saving an instance with a string that is within the max_length requirement.

These are my phonenumber_field settings

```py
PHONENUMBER_DB_FORMAT = "NATIONAL"
PHONENUMBER_DEFAULT_REGION = "US"
```

I create the object and save it to db

```py
# string length is 10 but settings above add "+1" to front when value is saved 
obj = User(..., phone_number='xxxxxxxxxx')
obj.save()
```

Comment: sqlite isn't considering the phone_code as part of field whereas postgres do, in this case you should increase the max_length of field

Comment: @UdayYadav I have tried increasing the max_length to 13 and it just returns the same error but instead of 12 it says ...varying(13)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I figured it out.**

If you get this error you should check the **local variables** as you trace the error. For me, I found out that when my phone number is saved, it saved with parentheses so it actually went over the 12 character limit.

I wanted to save: +13434344343 which is **12 chars**

But it was saved like this: (343) 434-4343  is **14 chars** long

I had to change my Django settings.py

```py
PHONENUMBER_DB_FORMAT = "E164"
PHONENUMBER_DEFAULT_REGION = "US"
```